# Is there a difference between these two uses of sizeof?

Tags: c++, sizeof

I want to allocate some space for a VBO. The function to do this (in OpenGL) is:

```
void glBufferData(GLenum  target,
                  GLsizeiptr  size,
                  const GLvoid *  data,
                  GLenum  usage);
```

In a tutorial i'm reading, the size is calculated by:

```
N_VERTS*P_SIZE*sizeof *pos,
```

where `N_VERTS` is the number of vertices and `P_SIZE` is the dimension (2D/3D...).

I'm using :

```
sizeof(pos)
```

Is there a difference between them? My tests didn't show any difference. Also what does this mean?

```
sizeof *pos
```

My guess was that it's equal to

```
sizeof(pos)/sizeof(float)
```

but my tests show me it's not.

**Edit:**

```
#define N_VERTS 3
#define P_SIZE 2

float pos[N_VERTS*P_SIZE] =
{
    -0.8, -0.8,
    0.8, -0.8,
    0.0, 0.8
};
```

Comment: Depends. What is `pos`?

Comment: sizeof *pos seems like it is using the element that pos is pointing to instead of pos. It looks weird that's all I'm saying

Comment: I am guessing that `pos` is a `float` array.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit added pos

Comment: With the definition of `pos` you've given, `*pos` and `pos` should have *very* different sizes (`sizeof(float)` vs. `sizeof(float)*N_VERTS*P_SIZE`). Are you sure that both work?

Comment: @delnan I just use a cout and get the same results. But if I was sure, I wouldn't come ask here to people more experienced than me

Comment: Unary `*` is the *dereference* operator. You don't need to guess; `*pos` means the object that `pos` is pointing to.  In your case, `pos` is an array. When you use the name of an array in a value context, it implicitly converts to a pointer to the first element of the array, i.e. `&pos[0]`. So you have `*(&pos[0])` which is the same as `pos[0]`. Since `pos[0]` has type `float`, `sizeof *pos` is `sizeof(float)`.

Comment: "I just use a cout and get the same results" - you did something wrong in your cout then, as `sizeof pos` is much larger than `sizeof *pos`, in fact, 6 times as big.

Comment: @bobthegoblinslayer Nevermind, I only just noticed you multiply `sizeof *pos` with the same expression that you use as array size. That should indeed be equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `sizeof *pos` is the same as `sizeof(*pos)`, and gives the size of the thing that `pos` points at. If `pos` is dynamically allocated, it will give you the size of each element.

So for example:

```
float *pos = new float[N_VERTS * P_SIZE]; 
// ... fill in pos values 
size = N_VERTS * P_SIZE * sizeof *pos;
```

will give the size of the memory allocated for `pos` in bytes.

In your case, since your data is not dynamically allocated, you could use `sizeof pos`.

Comment: sorry, I'm not understanding what would happen if i'm using `sizeof pos` when my data are allocated dynamically.

Comment: @bob It would give you the size of the pointer, i.e. 4 bytes on a 32 bit architecture.

Answer (score 1):

The grammar of the sizeof operator is defined the following way

```
sizeof unary-expression
sizeof ( type-id )
```

As any expression can be enclosed in parentheses then

```
sizeof unary-expression
```

is equivalent to

```
sizeof ( unary-expression )
```

In your example `sizeof( *pos )`  is the size in bytes of the element of array pos.

Expression `*pos` is equivalent to `pos[0]` that is it is the first element of the array.

`sizeof( pos )` is the size in bytes of array pos itself.

`sizeof( *pos )` is equivalent to `sizeof( float )` because `sizeof( *pos )` is the size of the element of array pos and each element has type float.

So

```
sizeof( pos ) / sizeof( float )
```

is equivalent to

```
sizeof( pos ) / sizeof( *pos )
```

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
float arr[3];
float *p = arr;


sizeof(arr) // gives 3*sizeof(float), i.e. on a compiler using IEEE 754 floats, 12.  
sizeof(p)   // gives just the _pointer_ size, e.g. 4 or 8.
sizeof(*p)  // gives sizeof(float), incidentally 4 as well, assuming IEEE 754 floats.
sizeof(arr[0]) // yields the float size as well, like *p.
```

sizeof is one of the few places where an array does **not** decay to a pointer, even if it looks like a function.

My guess is that the tutorial is right; they need the size of your pos array, 6*sizeof(float). Because pos is a true array, this is equal to sizeof(pos), what, I think, you used. Both ways are correct. But I find the tutorial's way safer because you may at some point pass that array around, or allocate it dynamically, and in that case you would suddenly deal with a pointer which has a smaller size while all the rest of the code sees no difference.

Comment: all your guesses are right. Intersting answer too. thank you.

Answer (score -1):

In this case, sizeof *pos would only make sense if pos is a pointer to something, in which case sizeof *ptr is a common idiom that gives the size of the referenced (pointed-to) object.

sizeof pos would only return the size of the pointer, ie. not the object size.

edit: after further details have been added to the question, it seems pos is an array, in which case sizeof pos returns the total size of the array (in bytes). however, if the array ever decays into a pointer, sizeof returns the size of an pointer on your system.

Comment: Doesn't seem clearer to me. `sizeof` isn't a function.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I wanted to write `sizeof pos`

Comment: @bobthegoblinslayer No.  sizeof(pos) will return 4 or whatever size pointers are on your system.  sizeof(*pos) will return the size of the array element which could be anything but in your case will also be 4 (just coincidentally mind you).

Comment: @JerryJeremiah and Shaggi: Note that in this case, `pos` is an array, not a pointer. You're right if it was a pointer, and this is worth mentioning beforehand, but with arrays it *does* work as intended.

Comment: @delnan yeah i edited the answer after i saw the edit on the topic :) maybe if however downvoted this would be kind enough to remove the downvote (afaik my answer is correct?)